# XSD - XNOR gate of 2 nodes

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I trying to create a XSD which validates XML only if both nodes A and B exist or both does not exist (XNOR gate).

I have checked the internet, however, without any luck.

```
<root>
   <A>a</A>
   <B>b</B>
   <C>c</C>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="root" type="root"/>
<xs:complexType name="root">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence></xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```